# Flutter StreamBuilder with duplicated snapshot

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-streambuilder

I have a StreamBuilder in order to build a Chat App, but there's an issue that it unexpectedly reloads with some events. At the time it reloads, the snapshot still got the same data in it, therefore some messages are repeatedly added to the List 'messages'.

[image: repeated_msg]

How can I prevent the StreamBuilder from doing this repetition?

Here is my StreamBuilder code:

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        reverse: true,
        child: Center(
          child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: channel.stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                addText(snapshot.data.toString(), 1); // adds to messages
              }
              return ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: messages.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 14, right: 14, top: 10, bottom: 10),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: (messages[index].messageType == 'receiver'
                          ? Alignment.topLeft
                          : Alignment.topRight),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          color: (messages[index].messageType == 'receiver'
                              ? Colors.grey.shade200
                              : Colors.blue[200]),
                        ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                        child: Text(
                          messages[index].messageContent,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

create a List in your state class and`if(snapshot.hasData){ List = snapshot.data; }`
then use the items in your list instead of your snapshot;